# python re.sub removes numeric characters palindrome

Tags: python, palindrome, python-re

I am trying to remove punctuation to check if a phrase (or word) is a palindrome, though when I have a word with numbers they are removed and it return True instead of False. "1a2" after cleaning punctuation with sub returns 'a' though it should still give me '1a2'. I thought I picked up only punctuation for substitution.

```
import re
def isPalindrome(s):
    clean = re.sub("[,.;@#?+^:%-=()!&$]", " ", s)
    lower = ''.join([i.lower() for i in clean.split()])
    if lower == lower[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(isPalindrome("1a2"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `-` inside your regex and you need to escape it correctly, try this instead:

```
re.sub("[,.;@#?+^:%\-=()!&$]", " ", s)
```

Have a look in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) for a list of special characters and how to note a `[]`.

Comment: only the `-` needs to be escaped within these brackets. see the `[]` section of the doc you pointed

Comment: Thanks @Demi-Lune you're absolutely right, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Special characters must be escaped in your regex string. I.e.

```
clean = re.sub(r"[,\.;@\#\?\+\^:%\-=\(\)!\&\$]", " ", s)
```

or use re.escape, which automatically escapes special characters

```
esc = re.escape(r',.;@#?+^:%-=()!&$')
clean = re.sub("[" + esc + "]", " ", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) and the punctuation set from the [string module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) in your case, because I think that this is more readable than a regex :

```py
import string
s = s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```